# Kafka cluster failover causes client consumer heartbeat thread to close spring application context

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, cluster-computing, failover, consumer

We have a multi-cluster kafka setup (prod/DR) with cluster replication and use a healthcheck service to dynamically determine cluster health both during startup, and dynamically during app normal operation.   The client apps run as spring boot + java 11, but I've seen the same behaviour running as plain old spring app.

In the app if we detect any exceptions of type RetriableException on either producer publish or consumer polling, we'll dynamically re-create the producer/consumer after doing a health service check to get the details for the healthiest cluster.

However, I'm seeing the following problem when I kill all brokers for the cluster we're currently connected to (e.g. simulating a complete data centre failure for our Prod cluster).

**Producers:**
After a 60 second delay an exception (kafka TimeoutException) bubbles out of the producer, and our app auto fails over and connnects to the DR cluster.  In-flight messages which we were posting to the Prod cluster at the time of the failure, get delivered fine after reconnecting.

**Consumers:**
Any apps with consumers suffer fatal issues.  The consumer heartbeat thread is unable to connect to any of the brokers in the cluster we were connected to (expected since I've killed all brokers).  It goes into a retry loop for 60 seconds (same as the producer), however after the 60 s retry is up, no exception bubbles out the poll call.  Instead it looks like either the kafka code either actively closes the spring app context, or kill a thread that results the same thing, and our app dies!  See stack trace below where the last line is the spring context closing.

```
16:59:53.952 [Thread-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Group coordinator XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (id: XXXXXXXXXX rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
16:59:54.127 [Thread-2] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Discovered group coordinator XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (id: XXXXXXXXXX rack: null)
16:59:54.482 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node XXXXXXXXXX terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
16:59:54.482 [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Group coordinator XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (id: XXXXXXXXXX rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
16:59:54.582 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 4 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
16:59:55.797 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
16:59:57.017 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 5 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
16:59:58.249 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
16:59:59.461 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 5 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
17:00:00.674 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
17:00:01.888 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 5 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
17:00:03.102 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
17:00:04.315 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 5 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
17:00:05.528 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.k.c.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, groupId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] Connection to node 2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before successfully committing the current consumed offsets
17:00:05.630 [Thread-0] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2ef5e5e3: startup date [Fri Apr 17 16:58:22 BST 2020]; root of context hierarchy
```

I've not dug into the kafka code yet to see exactly why it does this but it seems very odd behaviour to me.  Why would this be the default behaviour whey you can't connect to any brokers in the cluster?

Ultimately it won't affect us too much since we're running in Docker instance on Kubernetes, so the app context closing results in the death of our pod, and we connect fine to the healthy DR cluster when a new pod comes up.  However, i'm interested if anyone can comment on this behaviour - is it intentional?